# Get instagram ID from facebook graph API without manage_pages permission

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm creating an app that's using facebook login to get instagram follower insights. Currently I've followed and and successfully made the soloution written here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started/

But here's the problem. Facebook won't approve the "manage_pages" permission for my app. Without manage_pages I have no idea how to get the instagram account id.

I've tried for a couple of weeks now, and facebook won't give any explanation other than "This permission is not required for your app's intended function, or it doesn't appear to enhance the user experience" and then referencing this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

I currently have a facebook support ticket regarding the issue but they haven't replied for almost 2 weeks. And I'm getting a little desperate.

Using below URL for version 3.0 and 3.2 to get the instagram accounts - It works with "manage_permissions" but without it the response is empty.

```
me/accounts?fields=name,id,access_token,instagram_business_account{id}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has finally replied to my support ticket and accepted my app review! The approach and guide I was using above was correct.

Comment: Can you please help me with similar issue? i also using manage_pages and other permissions for instagram and its working with my facebook account but when i am login with test user with the same permissions, it not returning instagram_business_account id in API response and as i know we have to submit app with test account for review.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem to get Instagram Id without extra `manage_pages` permission. I see no point to ask users for `manage` page permissions (just read it - its includes ads/create/delete etc permissions, crazy) just to get their Instagram accounts id connected to the page. I've found `pages_read_engagement` permission will provide this data! So, read only permission fixed my problem. Try it! Its better than `manage_pages` I guess.

Comment: Hi I’m a bit lost on how to use instagram graph api to get info like followers, likes etc... it seems excessive to ask the user to have a facebook page connected to their insta. Did you find a way to avoid that?